# What are the advantages of DIVS over tables?

Tags: html

I am curious as to what are all the advantages of using DIV's over Tables and vice versa.

Thanks,
XaiSoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question gets asked a lot. Take a look at these:

[Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/div-vs-table)

[DIV's vs. Tables or CSS vs. Being Stupid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61250/divs-vs-tables-or-css-vs-being-stupid)

[Yet Another Divs vs Tables issue: Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339210/yet-another-divs-vs-tables-question-forms)

Comment: lol guess I should have searched first.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one:
[Tables instead of DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251/tables-instead-of-divs/30271)

To summarize all those links:

It's not div vs tables as much as it is *semantics* vs tables.  Div *and* tables (used *appropriately*) are each only a small part of a semantic layout.

There a number of reasons to use a good semantic layout.  Most of them come down to supporting "fringe" browsers, but you might be surprised how many of those there are:

- Screen readers and other accessible browsers (and if you work for the US government, your sites are *required* to work with these)
- Mobile browsers (smart phones)
- Older browsers (IE6 and earlier, netscape 4.x and earlier).  There's still a lot of IE6 out there.
- **Google** will do a better job indexing and ranking a semantic layout, and the google bot is just another kind of browser.

Also, you'll get better separation of content from function, making it easier to maintain the site between a separate designer and programmer