# Displaying tabular data in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-lists, tabular

I used to always use tables. However, I've been told that the use of tables are a big no-no in modern HTML design. What are some good and "accepted" ways to display tabular data in modern HTML?

I would like to do something like this:

```
First_Name   Last_Name    Phone Number
Britney      Spears       555-555-5555
Jon          Bon Jovi     444-444-4444
```

I'm not 100% clear on why I should not use a table for this. But I've seen people use `<li>`'s that they use CSS to make behave more like `<div>`'s

What is a good way to set up data like this using HTML and CSS?

Comment: Did you use search functionality?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/div-vs-table

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61250/divs-vs-tables-or-css-vs-being-stupid

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339210/yet-another-divs-vs-tables-question-forms

Comment: @MaunoV. I don't think those links could be helpful for OP's question as his question was related to the presentation of tabular data.

Comment: hmm. good point, I just felt that we are getting close to "table-overflow" because of similar questions! ;) But hopefully they serve as quick links to someone else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is a perfectly valid use for tables as described by the spec (emphasis mine):

> The table element represents a table; that is, data with more than **one
>   dimension.**

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html
http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/tabular-data.html#examples

Using CSS for tabular data is possible, but it quickly becomes prohibitively difficult to deal with 100% width, equal height of cells, text wrapping, overflow, etc. The layout and rendering models for tables are well-defined and optimized for these scenarios, whereas a `div` or a `dl` or `ol` is not.

There are different display types which support more table-like layouts on non-table elements, but these aren't well implemented at the moment.

See: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#table

Comment: The HTML5 draft is not a specification (in any normal meaning of the word), and it has some odd definitions. The applicable specification is HTML 4.01, and it says: “The HTML table model allows authors to arrange data -- text, preformatted text, images, links, forms, form fields, other tables, etc. -- into rows and columns of cells.” It does not even include a requirement on more than one dimension; a one-row table and a one-column table are possible, too, though somewhat reduced cases.

Comment: We may be debating semantics, but despite draft or recommendation status engineers are developing to these guidelines and so are browser manufacturers. If we were discussing some esoteric new concept then I might agree, but describing tabular data as being dimensional seems logical. Even a single row or single cell (or both) table still often has implicit dimensionality, and if it doesn't, it probably shouldn't be a table.

Answer (score 6):

You **should** use a table for this.

Its tabular data, so it belongs in a HTML table.

Tables have a bad reputation because of the overuse of them for layout. But they are not evil, and a perfectly acceptable element to use when displaying a table of data on a web page.

Answer (score 4):

For tabular data, use the table element ! That's its purpose, and it's still here ([see the HTML5 norm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html)) and recommended.

Simply don't use tables to layout your screen when you can do it with CSS (a little more than 99% of all cases).